# Escape table name MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, escaping

I have a little problem with escaping table name. I was so stupid that i choose "show" for the name of table. When I use mysqli connection the escaping works fine, but its not working with classical mysql connection. Any advise? 
Sorry for my English, I am not native speaker.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS year, nameShow 
FROM   `show`
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I get error as

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show' at line 2 –
```

Query

```
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS year, nameShow 
    FROM   `show`
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When you do this mistake always fire [RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html) command and give proper name to table :)

Comment: I got this error  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show' at line 2`

Comment: You can try to prefix the from with the database name (no need for backticks then). `FROM dbname.show`

Comment: I can not rename the table, because its running project and I will have to rename it and find it in the code.

Comment: I tried the prefix before I was posting the problem here. Its still not wokring. `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS year, nameShow 
        FROM   serialtracker.show
        
        ORDER BY  year asc
        LIMIT 0, 10
        You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show' at line 2`

Comment: try with `serialtracker.\`show\``

Comment: what data will be there for `$sWhere` ??

Comment: when I ran your query, I didn't face any problem in MY SQL 5.5 [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c03cf/1)

Comment: Its individual filtering, but in this case its empty. I am using Datables [link](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) . The code is from example on the bottom of the page.

Comment: I dont have problem with query when I copy the printed sql from browser and run it with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Finally I have got working query. I dont know why the others solutions werent working. But this works : `serialtracker.\`show\``

Comment: FWIW years later, perhaps no database had been set. E.g. `USE serialtracker;` before your query. That is, the error message may have been misleading in this circumstance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Section 9.3 of MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)  says back ticks (`) or double quotes ("), however, I'd go with Fahim Parkar's comment above and just rename the table.

Also worth noting, you must use ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode if using double quotes per [Section 9.2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html):

> If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to
>   quote identifiers within double quotation marks

Comment: Finally I have got working query. I dont know why the others solutions werent working. But this works : `serialtracker.\`show\``

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with YEAR not with SHOW. YEAR is a MySQL function.
Best practice is to quote column and tables names all the time, makes things easy to read also.

Should be:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `year`, `nameShow` 
FROM   `show`
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: MySQL does not restrict function names from being used in aliases. Only _reserved keywords_ are restricted in aliases. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html (only the `(R)` ones). (also not restricted in 5.5, 5.6 and 5.7)

Answer (score 1):

Backticks should work fine

try putting a comma after SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS,

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, year, nameShow 
FROM   `show`
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I know it should. But I dont know what am I doing wrong.   `$sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS year, nameShow 
        FROM   `show`
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
        ";`

Comment: @zdarsky.peter : Could you post your query in your question?? In above query what is $s after `show`?? I think that is your problem