# Sql query is not properly working: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to php and trying to make login form, but its showing an error

Failed to query databaseYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'form signup-form where email = 'mail@mail.com' AND psw = '12345'' at line 1

```
 <?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("jobportal" , $con);
    if(!$db)
      {         
        echo mysql_error();
      }
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
      {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $psw = $_POST['psw'];

        $query = mysql_query("select * form signup-form where email = '$email' 
          AND   psw = '$psw'") or die ("Failed to query database".mysql_error());

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        if($email=="$email" && $psw=="$psw")

        header('location:index.php');                  

       }

  ?>
```

Comment: Provide the query you are running. We will not be able to provide you an answer without that

Comment: Please review [ask]

Comment: Don't post (that much) code in the comments, edit your post and paste it there please

Comment: Use mysqli prepared statements with placeholders because your query is insecure.

Comment: Possible related: [Escape table name MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11004768/8097737)

Comment: Is there a reason why the question is tagged `mysql` instead of `mariadb`?

Answer (score 1):

You have spelling mistake in your query

Change

```
select * form signup-form where email = '$email' AND psw = '$psw'
```

To

```
select * from signup-form where email = '$email' AND psw = '$psw'
```

**You used `form` instead of `from`**

Comment: i'hv correct the spelling mistake but still seeing this error

Comment: For typo questions, flag/close the question as a typo.  Moving 1 character by 1 position is off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes:

1. Thanks to [@Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48187464/8097737)

   > **You used `form` instead of `from`**
2. You use a table-name with a `-` therefore you need to quote this table-name with a **backtick** `` ` ``.

So your query should be:

```
select * from `signup-form` where email = '$email' AND psw = '$psw'
```

Or try (with SQL_MODE = ANSI_QUOTES)

```
select * from "signup-form" where email = '$email' AND psw = '$psw'
```

---

From a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11004768/8097737) the [OP wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004768/escape-table-name-mysql#comment14382143_11004768) that adding the database-name helped, so you can also try:

```
select * from databasename.`signup-form` where email = '$email' and psw = '$psw'
```

(Replace *databasename* with your proper database-name for the table)

---

**Please note:**
 the shown sql-querys and your code are vulnerable to [SQL-Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), which will lead to errors and unintended behaviors based on the invalid/faulty user-input.

Please read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/8097737)

---

From the [MariaDB Knowledge Base: Identifier Names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/identifier-names/):

> The following characters are valid, and allow identifiers to be unquoted:
>
> - ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (numerals 0-9, basic Latin letters, both lowercase and uppercase, dollar sign, underscore)
> - Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
>
> (...)
>
> **Quote Character**
>
> The regular quote character is the backtick character - `` ` ``, but if the `ANSI_QUOTES` [SQL_MODE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/) option is specified, a regular double quote - `"` may be used as well.

Comment: @Umar is the error message exact the same? Also try to execute the query directly on the database without php or replace the parameters with fixed values.

Comment: working but sometimes says shows error,,,better than before...thnx

Comment: @Umar The errors must be triggered by the input from the user. Please read: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/8097737)

Comment: using mysqli method its working fine...Thanks a lot @devpuh