# SyntaxError Exception

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

   try{
       String fxmlName;
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url","root","password");
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       String qry = "select UpdateT from schema.update";
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry);


        fxmlName = rs.getString("UpdateT");
      // System.out.println(fxmlName);
       st.close();
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlName));

       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
       primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

       primaryStage.show();

   }
   catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println(e);
   }
}
```

Hey guys this is my code and its my first time on stack overflow and why I am getting this exception?

> java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

Comment: `select UpdateT from 'update'` ?

Comment: probably not the best idea to name a table "update"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape table name MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004768/escape-table-name-mysql)

Comment: Does the same query works when you run from the database? `select UpdateT from update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE` is a reserved word, so your DB objects should not use it. You can:

- change the table name (i 'd prefer this)
- use quotes every time to refer to that table